# No module named 'skvideo.io.ffmpeg' in the project

Tags: python, ffmpeg

Even though I have installed the scikit-video and installed ffmpeg, I still meet this problem: No module named 'skvideo.io.ffmpeg'

**output:**

````
(sd) huishi@huishi:~/workspace/projectsideo_python$ **pip install scikit-video**
Requirement already satisfied: scikit-video in /home/huishi/anaconda3/envs/sdb/python3.8/site-packages (1.1.11)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy in /home/huishi/anaconda3/envs/sdb/python3.8/site-packages (from scikit-video) (1.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pillow in /home/huishi/anaconda3/envs/sdb/python3.8/site-packages (from scikit-video) (9.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /home/huishi/anaconda3/envs/sdb/python3.8/site-packages (from scikit-video) (1.23.0)
(sd) huishi@huishi:~/workspace/projectsideo_python$ **sudo apt-get install ffmpeg**
正在读取软件包列表... 完成
正在分析软件包的依赖关系树       
正在读取状态信息... 完成       
ffmpeg 已经是最新版 (7:3.4.11-0ubuntu0.1)。
下列软件包是自动安装的并且现在不需要了：
  docker-scan-plugin gir1.2-goa-1.0 gir1.2-snapd-1
使用'sudo apt autoremove'来卸载它(它们)。
升级了 0 个软件包，新安装了 0 个软件包，要卸载 0 个软件包，有 20 个软件包未被升级。
(sd) huishi@huishi:~/workspace/projectsideo_python$ python RabbitMqUtils.py 
The license has expired.
/home/huishi/workspace/projectsideo_python/train_resource/train_split.py:12: YAMLLoadWarning: calling yaml.load() without Loader=... is deprecated, as the default Loader is unsafe. Please read https://msg.pyyaml.org/load for full details.
  tr_configs = yaml.load(f)
INFO: Created TensorFlow Lite XNNPACK delegate for CPU.
/home/huishi/anaconda3/envs/sdb/python3.8/site-packages/skvideo/__init__.py:306: UserWarning: ffmpeg/ffprobe not found in path: /usr/local/bin
  warnings.warn("ffmpeg/ffprobe not found in path: " + str(path), UserWarning)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "RabbitMqUtils.py", line 17, in <module>
    from video_postprocess import post_Process
  File "/home/huishi/workspace/projectsideo_pythonideo_postprocess/post_Process.py", line 12, in <module>
    import skvideo.io
  File "/home/huishi/anaconda3/envs/sdb/python3.8/site-packages/skvideo/io/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .ffmpeg import *
ModuleNotFoundError: **No module named 'skvideo.io.ffmpeg'**
(sd) huishi@huishi:~/workspace/projectsideo_python$```



I have tried to upgrade the pip and skvideo but it doesn't work. How can I solve this problem
````